# TrueZip on Android, UnsupportedCharsetException: IBM437

Tags: java, android, truezip

I'm trying to open zip file on Android 4.3 emulator using TrueZip 7.7.3

the line

```
TArchiveDetector ad  = new TArchiveDetector("myext", new ZipDriver(IOPoolLocator.SINGLETON));
```

throws `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` caused by 

`java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: IBM437
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:303)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.ZipDriver.<clinit>(ZipDriver.java:75)
        ... 16 more`

Is it possible to use TrueZip on Android? I need it because java.util.ZipFile on Android is old and cannot handle more than 65536 files in zip archive.

Answer (score 3):

TrueZIP on the Android platform is generally unsupported because the platform misses or used to miss some essential classes, e.g. `java.util.ServiceLoader`. Regarding the missing IBM437 character set: A provider is actually bundled into TrueZIP, but the `ServiceLoader` class is required to find and load it. You may try to use the `JarDriver` instead (which uses UTF-8 instead of IBM437), but I'm afraid you will only run into similar issues because TrueZIP depends a lot on the `ServiceLoader` class in order to load the kernel, the drivers, the extensions etc.

Comment: hi.. I have used this lib in my JAVA desktop application and its work fine but it is not supported in android as you said in answer, so i want to know about android support, or any other alternative open source libs are out there for android?

Comment: AFAIK, I'm afraid this hasn't changed. I don't have Android though, so I may be wrong.